# Fetch the location of a device no matter what state the app is inAlways detect the location from my corporate application

Tags: java, android, flutter, geolocation

I would like to get the location of corporate devices using a corporate application.

I've had success with locating the device when the application is in foreground but doesn't seem to work when the app is in the background or killed.

I tried to use push notification to start a service or broadcastReceiver when the app is closed or in background but nothing works.

Is there a way to fetch the location of a device no matter what state the app is in?

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.c7lab.fotodinamico">

    <!--
     io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Corporate Application">
        <receiver android:name=".MyLocationService"></receiver>


        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame"
                android:value="true" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <service
            android:name="com.example.crm_agenti.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**MyLocationService.class**

```
package com.c7lab.fotodinamico;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.location.Location;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationResult;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

import static android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE;


public class MyLocationService extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static final String ACTION_PROCESS_UPDATE = "com.c7lab.fotodinamico.UPDATE_LOCATION";
    private static final String TAG = "MyLocationService";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "MYSERVICE WORK?");
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("FlutterSharedPreferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String shared = prefs.getString("flutter.jsonData", null);
        JsonObject ed = new JsonObject();
        Gson g = new Gson();
        if(shared != null) {
            ed = new JsonParser().parse(shared).getAsJsonObject();
        }

        String usr = "no-usr";
        if(ed.get("usr") != null) {
            usr = ed.get("usr").getAsString();
        }
        if(intent != null) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            if(ACTION_PROCESS_UPDATE.equals(action)) {
                LocationResult result = LocationResult.extractResult(intent);
                if(result != null) {
                    Location location = result.getLastLocation();
                    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = location.getLongitude();

                    String location_string = new StringBuilder(""+latitude).append(" - ").append(longitude).toString();
                    Log.v(TAG,location_string);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.class**

```
package com.c7lab.fotodinamico;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

import com.karumi.dexter.Dexter;
import com.karumi.dexter.PermissionToken;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionDeniedResponse;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionGrantedResponse;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionRequest;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.single.PermissionListener;

import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;


public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
  private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
  private Handler mainHandler = new Handler();

  static MainActivity instance;
  LocationRequest locationRequest;
  FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;

  public static MainActivity getInstance() {
    return instance;
  }


  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);
    //scheduleJob();
    getWindow().addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);


    Dexter.withActivity(this)
            .withPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
            .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
              @Override
              public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse response) {
                  updateLocation();
              }

              @Override
              public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse response) {
                  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Accetta permessi posizione.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

              }

              @Override
              public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permission, PermissionToken token) {

              }
            }).check();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onStop() {
    // call the superclass method first
    super.onStop();

  }

    private void updateLocation() {
        buildLocationRequest();
        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, getPendingIntent());
    }

    private PendingIntent getPendingIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, com.c7lab.fotodinamico.MyLocationService.class);
        intent.setAction(com.c7lab.fotodinamico.MyLocationService.ACTION_PROCESS_UPDATE);

        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    }

    private void buildLocationRequest() {
        locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationRequest.setInterval(5000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(3000);
        locationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(10f);
    }


}
```

I have tried multiple solutions written on this site!

Answer (score 0):

A lot of issues.

1)Don't use getLastLocation.  This only works if the device already knows the location.  Instead, use requestSingleUpdate to actually turn on the location hardware.  This required you to use a real service, as a BroadcastReceiver would be killed too quickly.  The BR can start the service though.

2)You need a foreground service, not a background service.

3)IN modern android, the user can choose to grant location only when the app is open and block all background access.  Possibly a device policy owner can override this, not sure.  But if it can't, you're screwed.

Comment: 1) So i need to use locationManager instead of locationRequest?
2) I don't understand, why? In foreground i have the location from flutter main ( i ve edited the answer).
3) Yes not a problem, is a corporate device and users know what they can do or can't do